# VBA compare to column values

Tags: vba

i am new to VBA what i want to do is if cell column A is empty then cell in column B should also be empty and if cell column A as values then cell in columns B should have value in same row. if not meet then msg box error my code is below i have problems with 2nd of that condition its not showing me error when i have value in cell in column B but column A is empty. Pls help

```
Sub Denial_Reason1()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim lr As Long, target As Range

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each target In ws.Range("A2:A" & lr)
   If target <> "" And target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
    
    MsgBox "Error" & target.Address
    enter code here

   ElseIf target = "" And target.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
    
    MsgBox "Error" & target.Address
End If

  Next target
End Sub
```

Comment: You say columns A and B but your code works on T and U.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes sorry in my worksheet it is columns T & U i thought it would easer to illustrate my thinking on here if i just used A &B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Sub Denial_Reason1()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, vA, vB
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        vA = Len(c.Value)
        vB = Len(c.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        
        If (vA > 0 And vB = 0) Or (vA = 0 And vB > 0) Then
            MsgBox "Mismatch error at " & c.Resize(1, 2).Address
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: i made some adjusted as need looks like it works! thank you